# Solr Data Import Handler (DIH) fails to Index all the records from MySQL View

Tags: solr, dih

I have a View in my MySQL DB and building a POC of Solr Indexing using DIH. In my direct select query, there are 6 records, but the Solr query returns just 4 (even though it does say that it has Fetched 6 records).

MySql View

```
CREATE VIEW FORUMS_SURVEYS AS
SELECT F.TITLE, F.DESCRIPTION, F.CREATED, FC.TYPE, FC.SUBTYPE FROM FORUM F JOIN FORUM_CATEGORY FC ON F.FORUM_CATEGORY_ID=FC.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT S.TITLE, S.DESCRIPTION, S.DATED AS CREATED, "" AS TYPE, "" AS SUBTYPE FROM SURVEY S;
```

Select from the View

```
select * from FORUMS_SURVEYS;

Result - Fetched Rows: 6 (as expected)
```

Run DIH on Solr with the following

```
db-data-config.xml

<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bjm" user="<user>" password="<password>" />
    <document>
       <entity name="forums_surveys" query="SELECT * FROM forums_surveys" transformer="HTMLStripTransformer">
            <field column="TITLE" name="title" indexed="true" type="text" />
            <field column="DESCRIPTION" name="description" indexed="true" type="text" stripHTML="true"/>
            <field column="CREATED" name="created" indexed="true" type="text" />
            <field column="TYPE" name="type" indexed="true" type="text" />
            <field column="SUBTYPE" name="subtype" indexed="true" type="text" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

On UI Admin , Result of DataImport

```
Last Update: 16:13:12

(Duration: 01s)
Requests: 1 1/s, Fetched: 6 6/s, Skipped: 0 , Processed: 0 
Started: 42 minutes ago
```

Again, good to see the text "Fetched: 6"

However, things go unpleasant when I query the result from UI Admin with query Params q=title:* (notice the field in JSON below response > numFound)

```
"responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":8,
    "params":{
      "q":"title:*",
      "_":"1587565922553"}},
  "response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"docs":[
//removed the 4 records for brevity
]
```

Comment: WHat is unique id in your case?...what have you been configured in the schema.xml? there is a need to have unique field for your documents.

Comment: I don't see any field in your select as id field or a field which defines uniqueness of the row

Comment: Did you find the id field and resolved this one ?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti. Thanks for your comments. I have to figure out to ascertain the ID field of the records from View, shall try couple of ideas I have in my mind and following that will update the post.

Comment: Yes please...the issue seems of the unique id

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti. Many Thanks. It seem to work. The ID in the View is the concat of two fields and hence a String. Don't know what the efficiency would be. But will see when I cross the bridge - when I have large volume of Data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a unique field which can be id. The unique field is required to maintain the uniqueness of the documents of the solr.

The `uniqueKey` element specifies which field is a unique identifier for documents. Although uniqueKey is not required, it is nearly always warranted by your application design.

For example, `uniqueKey` should be used if you will ever update a document in the index.

You can define the unique key field by naming it:

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```